# How to set 'ok' in stk parsing using at-command?

Tags: at-command, modem, sim-toolkit

In the stk menu I got something like this:

```
+STIN: 1
AT+STGI=1
+STGI: 1," Press ok to complete transaction",1
```

This is the end of a transaction, I just need to press the ok button to complete it.

What at-command am I supposed to use here?

Comment: Hi how did you access the stk menu, am having an issues trying to access it, please look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/871174/simcard-tool-kit

Comment: @Tuna I used C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's should be only 3 command in STK, which is +STIN, +STGI, +STGR, it should be same with if STK require response such as 1,2,3,etc, so you may try with AT+STGR=1,1

Comment: @kabaehr, sorry for not answering this question myself, because I found the solution a long time ago. And yes what Angga Wirapraditya said is the correct answer and that's how its done.

Comment: how did you access the stk menu, am having an issues trying to access it, please look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/871174/simcard-tool-kit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AT^STGR?` to view possible answers (tested with Huawei Modems)